# Getting split message from Apache Camel split

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I have following camel configuration for split xml using a xpath.

```
from("direct:[nameofthetemplate]")
.split(xpath(xPath))
.end();
```

I need to get the items return from split and store them in an array list.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

So you want aggregate them http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html.

```
from("direct:[nameofthetemplate]")
.split(xpath(xPath)).aggregate()
.end();
```

But this is not create a java array list with xml node inside, just an XML composed of the nodes you split (it could be the initial message if it is initialy  composed only of nodes you split). If you need to process xml node just continue your camel route to processing one by one after split.